# Packer WinRM connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, packer, winrm

I'm using packer to create a Windows Host in GCP.

This is my packer file:

```
source "googlecompute" "windows-winrm-ansible" {
  image_name       = "windows-image-name"
  project_id       = var.google_project
  source_image     = var.source_image
  zone             = var.zone
  subnetwork       = var.subnetwork
  omit_external_ip = true
  use_internal_ip  = true
  machine_type     = var.machine_type
  disk_size        = 50
  communicator     = "winrm"
  winrm_username   = "packer_user"
  winrm_insecure   = true
  winrm_use_ssl    = true

  metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-cmd = "winrm quickconfig -quiet & net user /add packer_user & net localgroup administrators packer_user /add & winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic=\"true\"}"
  }
}

build {
  sources = ["sources.googlecompute.windows-winrm-ansible"]
}
```

I have also created a firewall rule to open the following ports:

- WinRM: 5985, 5986
- RDP: 3389
- HTTP: 80

When running the packer file above, he is able to create the .pem files fine, but it gets stuck in:

```
googlecompute.windows-winrm-ansible: Waiting for WinRM to become available...
```

Turning on debug I can see:

```
2022/03/15 13:56:40 packer-builder-googlecompute plugin: [INFO] Attempting WinRM connection...
2022/03/15 13:56:40 packer-builder-googlecompute plugin: [DEBUG] connecting to remote shell using WinRM
2022/03/15 13:56:40 packer-builder-googlecompute plugin: [ERROR] connection error: unknown error Post "https://XXXXXXX:5986/wsman": dial tcp XXXXXXX:5986: connect: connection refused
2022/03/15 13:56:40 packer-builder-googlecompute plugin: [ERROR] WinRM connection err: unknown error Post "https://XXXXXXX:5986/wsman": dial tcp XXXXXXX:5986: connect: connection refused
```

Which is weird because I'm able to RDP and running nc outputs this:

```
nc -z -w1 XXXXXXX 5986;echo $?
Connection to XXXXXXX port 5986 [tcp/wsmans] succeeded!
0
```

Inside the VM I can see:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
    ListeningOn = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

What could be the reason for packer to not be able to WinRM to the VM?

Comment: Are you running packer from your machine? Or from some tooling server? 
If you can log on from your machine, the packer should be able to connect. As I see `connection refused`, I guess there is a firewall in between the machine executing packer code & target VM provisioned by packer.

Comment: hey @harshavmb sorry for the lateness, I got busy with other tasks. Finally found the issue, my firewall rule to allow winrm was targeted for VMs with network tag "MY_TAG" but I was not creating a packer VM with such tag... adding `tag = ["MY_TAG"]` to my source `googlecompute.windows-winrm-ansible` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question if others run into the issue.

My "allow-winrm" firewall was targeting VMs with a specific tag. After adding that tag to the Packer VM it worked. See ** line bellow

```
source "googlecompute" "windows-winrm-ansible" {
  image_name       = "windows-image-name"
  project_id       = var.google_project
  source_image     = var.source_image
  zone             = var.zone
  subnetwork       = var.subnetwork
  omit_external_ip = true
  use_internal_ip  = true
  machine_type     = var.machine_type
  disk_size        = 50
  communicator     = "winrm"
  winrm_username   = "packer_user"
  winrm_insecure   = true
  winrm_use_ssl    = true
  **tags             = ["TAG_IN_FIREWALL"]**

  metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-cmd = "winrm quickconfig -quiet & net user /add packer_user & net localgroup administrators packer_user /add & winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic=\"true\"}"
  }
}

build {
  sources = ["sources.googlecompute.windows-winrm-ansible"]
}
```